# Checkout branch from Github without cloning whole repo, and without Git

Tags: git, bash, github, automation, git-checkout

I'm often building servers where the goal is to install some software that is stored in Github. The process goes:

1. Install Git.
2. Clone the Github repo.
3. Checkout the right branch.

Steps 1 and 2 can be pretty slow (a few minutes). Are there any tools that would allow me to cut to the chase, step 3? I'm thinking something like:

1. Get gitcheckout tool (bash script)
2. It directly pulls down the relevant files from the right branch in Github.

Comment: Github offers branch downloads as a zip file. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You could use wget to pull down the zip of the whole repository, but you cannot download individual parts so with most projects you'd wind up downloading a lot of extra data (unneeded branches, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use git and if your git is new enough to have `--single-branch`:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch=<branch> --depth=1
```

Otherwise, you can download the source in a zip:

```
wget https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<branch>.zip
```

Comment: Perfect - I didn't know you could do either of those things. I seem to recall once looking for the equivalent of "--single-branch" and it definitely not existing then.

Comment: After experimenting with both a bit, wget is faster, but with the possible downside that you don't end up with a git repo at all - which other scripts etc may expect.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could get a tarball using the GitHub API, and then you could get a branch and extract it in one go:

   ```
   curl -u USER:TOKEN https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/tarball/BRANCH -L | tar zt
   ```

   You can create your token following the steps on [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use).
   It's easy enough to do.
2. Or you could get a sub-directory using `svn`:

   ```
   svn checkout https://github.com/USER/REPO/branches/BRANCH/subdir/you/want
   ```

The good thing about both solutions is that they don't download the full history, only the snapshot of the latest state.

Comment: Very cool - two more (different) solutions. The SVN one is quite sneaky - but works because SVN is probably included in more distros than Git.

Answer (score 1):

curl or wget:

```
curl -o foo.zip https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<branch>.zip
wget https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<branch>.zip
```

that said, in my experience, installing git only takes a few seconds